# Deserialize complex JSON into Object - getting error Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON object string I am trying to deserialize into a C# object that I've created, but I keep getting the error during deserialization Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.

The JSON appears to have arrays within an array and I suspect that is what is causing the problem but I have not had any luck figuring out the exact issue.  I must admit I am new when it comes to handling JSON data and so I find myself here.

I've tried various things including an online tool to generate the class for me, but it's not giving me a desirable result.  None of the examples I've been able to find look quite like the JSON I am working with here which is causing me a bit of a roadblock.

The JSON in question:

```
{
  "a": "2019-08-08T19:34:25Z",
  "b": [
    {
      "c": "asdf"
    },
    [
      "d",
      "e",
      "f"
    ],
    {
      "g": "sdfg"
    },
    {
      "h": "dfgh"
    },
    {
      "i": "fghj"
    },
    {
      "j": "ghjk"
    },
    [
      "k",
      10,
      10
    ]
  ]
}
```

The objects I am trying to deserialize into:

```cs
    public class ClassA
    {
        public DateTime a { get; set; }
        public List<ClassB> b { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public string c { get; set; }
        public List<string> stringList1 { get; set; }
        public string g { get; set; }
        public string h { get; set; }
        public string i { get; set; }
        public string j { get; set; }
        public List<string> stringList2 { get; set; }
    }
```

and lastly, the code I am using to deserialize:

```cs
ClassA jclassa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassA>(strdata);
```

I'm hoping I can load this JSON into this class without introducing too much exotic looking stuff.

Comment: Your array is not a `List<ClassB>`, because it contains arrays as well. You'll have to write a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to handle that array. Or make `b` a `JArray` instead.

Comment: Use https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1):

The JSON that you use have different structure than the object class that you want to deserialize into.

An example of JSON that match your object will be something like this

```
{
  "a": "2019-08-08T19:34:25Z",
  "b": [
    {
      "c": "asdf",
      "stringList1": [
        "d",
        "e",
        "f"
      ],
      "g": "sdfg",
      "h": "dfgh",
      "i": "fghj",
      "j": "ghjk",
      "stringList2": [
        "k",
        10,
        10
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```